# Pepperflash not working in Cefsharp version 65.0.0.0

Tags: cefsharp, ppapi

We have recently upgraded **Cefsharp** to **65.0.0.0** from **43.0.0.0** in one of our projects. After the upgrade flash no longer loads in browser, it gives an error that

> "Adobe Flash player is out of date"

. We have embedded a specific version of **pepperflash 25.0.0.171** in the project. the code snippet as below

```
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Remove("enable-system-flash");
string PpapiFlashVersion = "25.0.0.171";
var pepFlashPlayerPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase,"pepflashplayer");                
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("ppapi-flash-path", pepFlashPlayerPath);
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("ppapi-flash-version", PpapiFlashVersion);
```

After getting the error I thought I'll try to use the latest version of **pepper flash (31.0.0.108)**. But when I do that I get another error

> "Right click to run Adobe Flash player"

Doing the right click doesn't work either.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you load `chrome://version/` in the browser does it say that flash was loaded? Version `67` is the latest version of `CefSharp`, you should test with that. Also you should try using the system wide flash install, make sure that works correctly.

Comment: There is similar problem with version 67.  I get the following information when loading chrome://version/                                                                         
CEF 3.3396.1786.gd3e36d0
Chromium 67.0.3396.79
OS Windows
WebKit 537.36 (@161bdad7314804dc8c72f850396fcd696e8863e8)
JavaScript 6.7.288.44
Flash 25.0.0.171

Comment: Try the system wide install. It's possible that specifying the command line arguments don't work anymore.

Comment: Systemwide install does work. But we have a scenario where if the flash is not installed, we could provide it as part of the package and instruct cefsharp to use it.

Comment: If you load chrome://version with system wide how does that compare?

Comment: The only difference in flash version. Below are the details for system wide   
CEF 3.3396.1786.gd3e36d0
Chromium 67.0.3396.79
OS Windows
WebKit 537.36 (@161bdad7314804dc8c72f850396fcd696e8863e8)
JavaScript 6.7.288.44
Flash 31.0.0.108

Comment: Make sure your specifying the correct version number, if that doesn't work then I've got no idea. As I've said, no guarantee it works anymore. It's whatever `Chromium` supports at the time.

Comment: We have found a workaround where if we change the version number to a higher non existent number, 
the embedded version does work. 
e.g. 

 pepFlashPlayerPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"resources/pepperFlash/win/32/pepflashplayer32_28_0_0_126.dll";
 
    settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("ppapi-flash-path", pepFlashPlayerPath);
    settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("ppapi-flash-version", "200.0.0.126");  

 Here the actual dll version is 28.0.0.126, but we are setting it to 200.0.0.126

Comment: You really should use the latest version of `Flash`, using an old version is a potential security risk.

Comment: For some reason the work that we have found doesn't work with the latest version(31.0.0.108)

Comment: Also following this question. Would like some solutions for Cef 75 with PPAPI Flash 32.